# MongoDB for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, macports

I'm trying to install MongoDB via macport for my Rails project. However when I tried to install MongoDB I got the following error. I don't understand why it's trying to download Python dependencies, could that be why it is failing?

```
hansarijanto$ sudo port install mongodb
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for mongodb
--->  Dependencies to be installed: boost bzip2 icu libpcap pcre scons python27 db46 python_select snappy lzo2 spidermonkey nspr readline
--->  Fetching archive for bzip2
--->  Attempting to fetch bzip2-1.0.6_0.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/bzip2
--->  Attempting to fetch bzip2-1.0.6_0.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/bzip2
--->  Installing bzip2 @1.0.6_0
--->  Activating bzip2 @1.0.6_0
--->  Cleaning bzip2
--->  Fetching archive for icu
--->  Attempting to fetch icu-4.8.1_0.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/icu
--->  Attempting to fetch icu-4.8.1_0.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/icu
--->  Installing icu @4.8.1_0
--->  Activating icu @4.8.1_0
--->  Cleaning icu
--->  Fetching archive for boost
--->  Attempting to fetch boost-1.49.0_0.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/boost
--->  Attempting to fetch boost-1.49.0_0.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/boost
--->  Installing boost @1.49.0_0
--->  Activating boost @1.49.0_0
--->  Cleaning boost
--->  Fetching archive for libpcap
--->  Attempting to fetch libpcap-1.1.1_0.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/libpcap
--->  Attempting to fetch libpcap-1.1.1_0.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/libpcap
--->  Installing libpcap @1.1.1_0
--->  Activating libpcap @1.1.1_0
--->  Cleaning libpcap
--->  Fetching archive for pcre
--->  Attempting to fetch pcre-8.12_1.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/pcre
--->  Attempting to fetch pcre-8.12_1.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/pcre
--->  Installing pcre @8.12_1
--->  Activating pcre @8.12_1
--->  Cleaning pcre
--->  Fetching archive for db46
--->  Attempting to fetch db46-4.6.21_6.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/db46
--->  Attempting to fetch db46-4.6.21_6.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/db46
--->  Installing db46 @4.6.21_6
--->  Activating db46 @4.6.21_6
--->  Cleaning db46
--->  Fetching archive for python_select
--->  Attempting to fetch python_select-0.3_1.darwin_11.noarch.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/python_select
--->  Attempting to fetch python_select-0.3_1.darwin_11.noarch.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/python_select
--->  Installing python_select @0.3_1
--->  Activating python_select @0.3_1
--->  Cleaning python_select
--->  Fetching archive for python27
--->  Attempting to fetch python27-2.7.3_0.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/python27
--->  Fetching python27
--->  Attempting to fetch Python-2.7.3.tar.xz from http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/python27
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for python27
--->  Extracting python27
--->  Applying patches to python27
--->  Configuring python27
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install python27
Log for python27 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: scons python27 snappy lzo2 spidermonkey nspr readline
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading mongo directly instead of installing it via macports?

Comment: Ok I know this isn't all that helpful, but these days you'll find you have _far_ better luck with [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) than macports. See if you can install it from there.

Comment: I want to try to install mongo db directly. I downloaded mongo-osx-x86_64-2.0.4.tgz and unzipped and moves the folder to /usr/local/mongodb. What do I need to do next to get mongodb set up?

Comment: Seriously don't bother. Just use homebrew on your mac, and use the 10gen mongo packages when you deploy: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

Comment: If you download the package you just need to run the mongodb binary once you have (of course you can do more stuff to tweak config settings etc.) homebrew is also super easy. Macports is probably installing python so that it can build the python bindings for mongodb - it does annoying stuff like that

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. I was just to used to mysQL with its fancy UI interface that mongod's unix interface scared the bejibers out of me hahaha. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts has been eclipsed by [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) as the package manager for OS X.  You can easily [install MongoDB with brew](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/).

Answer (score -1):

The MacPorts install works. It takes forever to install boost. Set it off and go get some lunch like they did in the punch card days.